# Calling non-static constexpr member function in template definition

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <type_traits>

template<size_t S> struct A
{
    constexpr size_t size() const noexcept { return S; } // Not static on purpose!
};

struct B : public A<123> {};

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of_v<A<T().size()>, T>, bool>::type // (*)
f(const T&, const T&) noexcept { return true; }

int main() {
    B b1, b2;
    f(b1, b2);
}
```

In my original question in (*) line I mistakenly used `T()::size()`, which is obviously incorrect since `size()` is not static.
The code works with `T().size()` and `std::declval<T>().size()`. So the question now is what is the difference and if any of these ways are more correct or better?

Comment: It looks like you expect `size` to be `static`. But then you `const` qualify it, like a non-static member.  Which is it?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica size() must not be static.

Comment: @PowerGamer: Then don't use `size` here. Use a static `constexpr` function/variable instead.

Comment: You have completely changed the question: this is highly confusing for future readers: two answers that are correct for your original question, doesn't make sense for the new version. You should create a new question, not modify the question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which compiler you're using, but gcc's error message offers a big honking clue:

```
t.C:12:52: error: cannot call member function ‘constexpr size_t A<S>::size() const
[with long unsigned int S = 123; size_t = long unsigned int]’ without object
```

After adjusting the declaration of the method accordingly:

```
static constexpr size_t size() noexcept { return S; }
```

gcc then compiled the shown code without issues.

If your intent is really to have `size()` be a regular class method, then you'll need to use `std::declval` instead of invoking it as a static method, in your template.

Answer (score 0):

`size` is a non-static function and requires an object to call. Make it `static` and remove `const`.